# Full REPL not supported

Tags: php, terminal, laravel

I get an error when trying to use artisan command tinker. For example I would like to add a user. In my terminal I type

```
$ php artisan tinker
```

but when I enter it I get a warning saying:

```
Full REPL not supported. Falling back to simple shell.
```

What could the problem be for this error? Is it my terminal, php, permissions or something else?

After I get the warning I can type to create new user but it doesn't save it to the database. I'm not sure what REPL is.

Comment: Artisan uses [Boris](https://github.com/d11wtq/boris) as REPL. You are getting the error because Boris depends on some extensions that need to be installed - check https://github.com/d11wtq/boris#will-it-work-with, so if you don't have those installed artisan will fallback to simple shell. So first make sure to install the necessary extensions if you want a full REPL support.

Comment: are you on windows?that's why.

Comment: boris is installed on default for laravel 4.1

see last post
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2215

I'm using mac os maverics

Comment: I'm getting this on Debian 7. I don't understand what packages I could be missing, it appears I have all the requirements it lists.

Comment: For others on OS X using Macports who arrive at this question, I installed `php54-pcntl` and `php54-posix` to get Boris working on Mavericks.

Comment: I personally use MAMP and also rely on MAMP's version of PHP for the CLI. When I hit this issue I found that

Answer (score 5):

If you are on debian like me this should work:

source: http://pkgs.org/debian-wheezy/dotdeb-i386/php5-readline_5.4.28-1~dotdeb.1_i386.deb.html

Add the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org/ wheezy all
```

Install GPG key of the repository:

```
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install php5-readline deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline
```

Comment: In my Ubuntu system, I was able to install it directly: `sudo apt-get install php5-readline`

Answer (score 1):

One or more of `readline` `posix` and `pcntl` extensions are missing.
You need to compile PHP with the appropiate configuration options to enabled it.

Here are the instructions:

- readline http://www.php.net/manual/en/readline.installation.php
- pcntl http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php
- posix http://www.php.net/manual/en/posix.installation.php

Note that posix functions are enabled by default.

Comment: On Centos 6.5, these are provided by the "php-cli" and "php-process" packages

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes pcntl functions are disabled in some distros, so you have to

Find your cli's `php.ini` file

```
php --ini
```

Edit it that `php.ini`, usually you'll have to do

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

or

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

and comment a line that starts with

```
; disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,...
```

You don't really have to comment it all, you can just enable pcntl functions, by removing them from that line, but if this is a development box, you can just enable everything.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use MAMP and also rely on MAMP's version of PHP for the CLI. When I hit this issue I found that the Redline and PCNTL extensions were not part of MAMP's PHP distribution.

I wrote an article on how I fixed the problem as well as a link to download the two extensions that I had to compile from source.

http://adampatterson.ca/blog/2014/10/laravel-tinker-boris-mamp-os-x-yosemite/