# "Full REPL not supported. Falling back to simple shell" - error in Laravel While Trying To Use php artisan tinker

Tags: laravel-4, wampserver, command-line-interface

My Development Environment:

- Windows 7 + WAMP
- PHP Version: 5.4.16

While I try to use php artisan tinker - my console give me the following error:

> REPL not supported. Falling back to simple shell

I search solution for this and found this :

[Full REPL not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861570/full-repl-not-supported)

But this could not helped me much.I know Boris is By default supported by laravel 4.1.
And I might do some changes in php.ini according to this.

> If the tinker command doesn't work for you, it is very likely the disable_functions setting in your php.ini contains the needed pcntl_() functions. Put a comment before this line in your php.ini and that should allow tinker to work.

Source :http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/280

But when I Open my php.ini file the disable_functions contains nothing except this:

disable_functions =

; This directive allows you to disable certain classes for security reasons.

; It receives a comma-delimited list of class names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.

; http://php.net/disable-classes

Is this My WAMP problem? Do I Missing Something !!!

Comment: Have you installed some repl processor? LIke Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Boris In Tinker
>
> The php artisan tinker command now utilizes the Boris REPL if your system supports it. The readline >and pcntl PHP extensions must be installed to use this feature. If you do not have these extensions, >the shell from 4.0 will be used.

From the Laravel docs here:
http://laravel.com/docs/releases

So basically, they are telling you that php55-pcntl and readline needs to be installed.

Everytime I try to `brew install php55-pcntl` though, I get

`configure: error: Cannot find openSSL's <evp.h>`

Try running that and see what you get.

**UPDATE: Use Laravel's Homestead environment**

I completely gave up trying to run it on a XAMPP/WAMP/MAMP-style localhost.

If you go to the quickstart docs and scroll down to local development environment:

http://laravel.com/docs/quick#local-development-environment

It actually recommends you use Laravel's custom homestead environment:

http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Read the docs for installing that and report back with results. It has been working perfectly for me.

Comment: The readline and pcntl PHP extensions must be installed to use this feature.- thanks.. :) But That arise another problem.. how do I install  readline and pcntl PHP extensions in my WAMP ??

Comment: See my new answer on trying the homestead hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of readline posix and pcntl extensions are missing. You need to compile PHP with the appropiate configuration options to enabled it.

Here are the instructions:

```
readline http://www.php.net/manual/en/readline.installation.php
pcntl http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php
posix http://www.php.net/manual/en/posix.installation.php
```

Note that posix functions are enabled by default.