# laravel tinker Full REPL not supported. Falling back to simple shell.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error `Full REPL not supported. Falling back to simple shell.` while trying to run `php artisan tinker`.

I'm using windows 8.1, xampp and laravel 5. I have looked at `php.ini` file and there aren't any disabled functions ( `disable_functions =` )

Comment: Is this a possibility? Some people have said MAMP doesn't have the correct dependencies, this coup be true for XAMPP as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861570/full-repl-not-supported

Comment: I have found the reason - it can't work on windows

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Laravel Homestead Vagrant box - it will give you access to the proper REPL. Better yet, it will provide a pretty similar environment to Laravel Forge if that is what you're using to deploy.